# Insert value to database and return another value with Ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to insert data to database via ajax

when the user login to facebook it will call the function 
which will return user id

my code

```
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.id);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, <b>' + response.name + '!</b><br>';


        document.getElementById('pic').innerHTML = "<img class='image-wrap' style=' width: 100px; height: 100px;' id='profileImage' src='http://graph.facebook.com/" + response.id + "/picture?width=180&height=180'>"

function callPHP(params) {
    var httpc = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    var url = "test.php";
    httpc.open("POST", url, true); 

    httpc.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpc.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", params.length); 

    httpc.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if(httpc.readyState == 4 && httpc.status == 200) { 
        alert(httpc.responseText); 
        }
    }
    httpc.send(params);
}



callPHP(response.id);

  }
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
// configuration
$dbtype     = "sqlite";
$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "test";
$dbuser     = "root";
$dbpass     = "1234";

// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

// new data
$link = $_GET;
$crr = rand(5, 15);

// query
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (link,crr) VALUES (:link,:crr)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':link'=>$link,
                  ':crr'=>$crr));

echo $crr;
?>
```

I want to insert ( response.id ) to database 
and return ( $crr )

but I'am getting empty value
or I get ( 500 (Internal Server Error) )

Comment: `500 Internal Server Error` is not enough information for us to assist.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - `$_GET` is a array. Converting array to string means you get string `'Array'` in you field.

Second - `':link'=>$lnik,`. So is it `$link` or is it `$lnik`. Fix your typo.

And third - read error logs. **Always**.

Comment: Moreover, the ajax request is sent via post to test.php, but in test.php $_GET is processed.